# Dynamic global array in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want a global array that I can access through controller functions, they can either add or delete any item with particular key. How do I do this? I have made my custom controller '`globals.php`' and added it on autoload library.

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
  $notification_array = array();
  $config['notification'] = $notification_array;
?>
```

following function on controller should add new item to my array

```
function add_data(){
   array_unshift($this->config->item('notification'), "sample-data");
}
```

after add_data adds to the global array, whenever following function is called from client, it should give the updated array to the client.

```
function send_json()
{
   header('content-type: application/json');
   $target = $this->config->item('notification');
   echo json_encode($target);
}
```

But my client always gets empty array. How can I make this happen? Please help.

Comment: please, forget about global variables, you are in OOP extend your controller class and declare your "global variable" there, you can acces it from any controller that is extended by it. Tutorial is [here](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY).

Comment: No problem, if you have troubles with it comment here again.

Comment: Well I've made array global, but it seems I cannot add another item
I tried $this->global_array['mykey']="Ashok"; on add_data() function, but when I display the global_array, I don't have this new item.

Comment: Try `array_push()`, and print it out `var_dump($variable)`. Please also note that any function in MY_Controller.php is avalible thru `$this->function();` so you can have your `send_json` declared in MY_Controller, but call it in (imaginable) `about` controller.

Comment: I've tried out, array has new element only within add_data function, but when I access array with send_json function, only default items comes. send_json is frequently called by client so I don't want database or file for persistent data. Isn't there any way around?

Comment: Yey, but if you "reload" / "refresh" page every data/`$variables` (except that are in DB, file, session, cookies) are "lost", are you sure you have the right concept? You need to go thru your code read it "line by line" if there is a change in URL and you call different methods do not except same PHP variables. Every time you refresh/reload/send new GET || POST request you call constructors etc. Data that stay are just that in DB/Files etc. I am saying exactly same as @umefarooq in his comment. You need session to do this I guess.

Comment: see my answer, there is walkthrough for "session" solution

Answer (score 1):

Hi take advantage of OOP, like this

// put MY_Controller.php under core directory

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{

  public $global_array = array('key1'=>'Value one','key2'=>'Value2'):

   public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

//page controller

```
class Page extends MY_Controller{

public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

function send_json()
{
   header('content-type: application/json');
   $target = $this->global_array['key1'];
   echo json_encode($target);
}

}
```

Comment: I can access the $global_array, but how to add another item to it from add_data function so that the value will be persistent and can be accessed anytime later with send_json function?

Comment: if you are calling add_data with in send_json then it will be persistent, because with each call of controller you will get only default values

Comment: Well I cannot do that, there are other functions too, that can change the array. send_json should send the latest array, not default. how is it  possible??

Comment: if you want persistent array save it in either session or in db create temp table better to go with session use session flash data

Comment: which one is faster? My client need to access the send_json frequently, I don't want to create much overhead.

Comment: go for session but if yo will use this with login, on logout whole session will flush out, or when session expired then too, in that case you have to check in MY_Controller if session don't have value set your default define values.

Comment: not really, you just need to delete the session that you use, I do this all the time, see my answer. You just delete "desired" session variable.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I came up is to use session, its easy to use and its "fast" you need to do some benchmarking.

As I commented on both answers above/below there is no way you get same data in different controllers just because with each request everything is "reset", and to get to different controller you need to at least reload tha page. (note, even AJAX call makes new request)

Note that sessions are limited by size, you have a limit of 4kb (CodeIgniter stores session as Cookie) but wait, there is way around, store them in DB (to allow this go to config file and turn it on `$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;` + create table you will find more [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html))

Well lets get to the answer itself, as I understand you tried [extending](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY) all your controllers if no do it and place some code in that core/MY_Controller.php file 
as follows:

```
private function _initJSONSession() { //this function should be run in MY_Controller construct() after succesful login, $this->_initJSONSession(); //ignore return values

    $json_session_data = $this->session->userdata('json');

    if (empty($json_session_data )) {

    $json_session_data['json'] = array(); //your default array if no session json exists,
                                          //you can also have an array inside if you like

        $this->session->set_userdata($ses_data);
        return TRUE; //returns TRUE so you know session is created
    }

return FALSE; //returns FALSE so you know session is already created

}
```

you also need these few functions they are self explainatory, all of them are public so you are free to use them in any controller that is extended by MY_Controller.php, like this

`$this->_existsSession('json');`

```
public function _existsSession( $session_name ) {

    $ses_data = $this->session->userdata( $session_name );

    if (empty( $ses_data )) return FALSE;

    return TRUE;

}

public function _clearSession($session_name) {

    $this->session->unset_userdata($session_name);

}

public function _loadSession($session_name) {

    return (($this->_existsSession( $session_name )) ? $this->session->userdata($session_name) : FALSE );

}
```

the most interesting function is `_loadSession()`, its kind of self explainatory it took me a while to fully understand session itself, well in a few words you need to get (load) data that are in session already, do something with it ([CRUD] like add new data, or delete some) and than put back (**REWRITE**) all data in the same session.

---

Lets go to the example:

keep in mind that session is like 2d array (I work with 4+5d arrays myself)

`$session['session_name'] = 'value';`

```
$session['json'] = array('id' => '1', 'name' => 'asok', 'some_array' => array('array_in_array' => array()), 'etcetera' => '...');
```

so to write new (**rewrite**) thing in session you use

```
{
    $session_name = 'json';

    $session_data[$session_name] = $this->_loadSession($session_name);

    //manipulate with array as you wish here, keep in mind that your variable is
    $session_data[$session_name]['id'] = '2'; // also keep in mind all session variables are (string) type even (boolean) TRUE translates to '1'

    //or create new index
    $session_data[$session_name]['new_index'] = FALSE; // this retypes to (string) '0'

   //now put session in place

    $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);

}
```

---

if you like to use your own function `add_data()` you need to do this

1. well you need to pass some data to it first `add_data($arr = array(), $data = ''){}`

eg: `array_unshift( $arr, $data );`

```
{
    //your default array that is set to _initJSONSession() is just pure empty array();  

    $session_name = 'json';        
    $session_data[$session_name] = $this->_loadSession( $session_name );

    // to demonstrate I use native PHP function instead of yours add_data()
    array_unshift( $session_data[$session_name], 'sample-data' );

    $this->session->set_userdata( $session_data );
    unset( $session_data );
}
```

That is it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "global" array per controller.

At the top of your controller:

```
public $notification_array = array();
```

Then to access it inside of different functions you would use:

```
$this->notification_array;
```

So if you want to add items to it, you could do:

```
$this->notification_array['notification'] = "Something";
$this->notification_array['another'] = "Something Else";
```

Comment: This is right answer I think in a way he needs only one controller + data, just because if he uses "MY_Controller" that extends his all controllers there is no way he is going to get same data (in different controller), just because everytime controller is called default array is set to begin with. He needs some persistant solution like session/cookies/files/database.